# Oracle Apex unique column alias on query generated by Pl/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to get report which query is being dynamically pulled by PL/SQL block.
I got inspiration from
[this article](http://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/apex-4-charts-dynamically-adding-a-series-2/) 
number of columns is dynamic and depend on the loop:

```
declare
l_qry VARCHAR2(4300);
s_qry VARCHAR2(80) := 0;
v_resort_id NUMBER := 1;

begin

l_qry := 'select a.column1,';

FOR pci in ( select id,name from table_pci where resort_id = v_resort_id) LOOP

s_qry := s_qry||'package.some_function (a.id,''' || pci.id || ''' , ''PC'') Property_type,' ;

 END LOOP;

   l_qry := l_qry ||s_qry;

   l_qry := l_qry||'a.column2 from features a where a.feature_type = ''condition1'' ';


return(l_qry);

end;
```

Property_type is hardcoded alias on the dynamic column, so everytime loop goes round it will try to generate column with the same name and Apex with flag it as error.If I select 
*Use Generic Column Names (parse query at runtime only)* it return correct number of columns but named Col1,Col2,Col3...

If I try to grab something dynamic from table_pci like name, I tried:

```
s_qry := s_qry||'package.some_function (a.id,''' || pci.id || ''' , ''PC'') '''|| pci.name || ''',' ;
```

I get error

```
failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Any help with finding a way to dynamicaly name the column greatly appreicated.
Any pointers, any advices and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a syntax error in your attempt to use a dynamic column alias.

Try:

```
s_qry := s_qry||'package.some_function (a.id,''' || pci.id || ''' , ''PC'') AS '|| pci.name || ',' ;
```

If the value in `pci.name` potentially has spaces in it them enclose it with double quotes:

```
s_qry := s_qry||'package.some_function (a.id,''' || pci.id || ''' , ''PC'') AS "'|| pci.name || '",' ;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: you are life saver. Second option had worked - your " '|| pci.name||' "   is somehow different for Apex from '''|| pci.name||'''

Comment: Glad it helped. If you enclose the column alias in double quotes (the second example) then it can tolerate spaces and other characters.